# Force reload Javascript-file on publish WITHOUT server code in view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, http-redirect

I have a project that uses a Javascript-File for its logic:

```
<script src="myMagicCode.js" ></script>
```

When I publish a new Version, clients have to clear the cache for the new code to work.

I usually can get around this problem by adding a parameter:

```
<script src="myMagicCode.js?version=1.23" ></script>
```

But I am too lazy to do this on each release. So I want to automate this behavior.

**The page containing the script-reference is pure html and can not contain any server code.**

I have however server code that returns the version.

So my idea would be to change the script - code to something like

```
<script src="api/GetJsUrl"></script>
```

Where `api/GetJsUrl` is a GET-Action which contains something like

```
string url = "myMagicCode.js?Version="+GetCurrentVersion();
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Location", url);
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(307);
```

Will this force the browser to reload the JS-File when a new version is published? Or will just the `api/GetJsUrl`-Request be cached and I have the same issue like before?

If there are still issues: Are there better solutions?

*Remark*: I do NOT search for a solution that reloads the JavaScript-File every time. I need a solution that only reloads the file when I deploy a new release (the version number changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a task runner like Grunt or Gulp:

http://gruntjs.com/

http://gulpjs.com/

They can lint, minify, build some things AND do what you want, looking to some properties file that contains the project version and editing your html.
They even can join your js file to one and replace it on your index.html:

```
 <script src="compiled.js?_=1234567890"></script>
```

Comment: We already use gulp (for other stuff) in that project. I will have a look. Thx